# Tempo corrido (Calculo de datas) - Vinda do Bando de Dados

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Galera alguém poderia me ajudar a encontrar oque está errado ao chamar a data do banco de dados na função, estou anexando também um print: 
Na esquerda o valor real do último acesso e na direita seria responsável por pegar a data da esquerda e fazer o cálculo do tempo decorrido.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<?php
include_once "conexao.php";
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');  
//consultar no banco de dados
$result_usuario = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(data_acesso, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%i:%s') as data_acesso FROM adms_ultimos_acessos WHERE adms_usuario_id = '44'  ";
$resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario) ;
$registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario ); // <--- esta linha


//Verificar se encontrou resultado na tabela "usuarios"
if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado_usuario) > 0){
    ?>

    <?php  

    function tempo_corrido($time) {

    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');     

     //$time = '2019/03/02 18:54:10';
     $time = $registro['data_acesso']; // <-- aqui está o registro
     $now = strtotime(date('Y/m/d H:i:s'));
     $time = strtotime($time);
     $diff = $now - $time;

     $seconds = $diff;
     $minutes = round($diff / 60);
     $hours = round($diff / 3600);
     $days = round($diff / 86400);
     $weeks = round($diff / 604800);
     $months = round($diff / 2419200);
     $years = round($diff / 29030400);

    if ($seconds <= 60) return"1 min atrás";
     else if ($minutes <= 60) return $minutes==1 ?'1 min atrás':$minutes.' min atrás';
     else if ($hours <= 24) return $hours==1 ?'1 hrs atrás':$hours.' hrs atrás';
     else if ($days <= 7) return $days==1 ?'1 dia atras':$days.' dias atrás';
     else if ($weeks <= 4) return $weeks==1 ?'1 semana atrás':$weeks.' semanas atrás';
     else if ($months <= 12) return $months == 1 ?'1 mês atrás':$months.' meses atrás';
     else return $years == 1 ? 'um ano atrás':$years.' anos atrás';
     }                                  

    ?>
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Data acesso</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                while($registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario)){
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th><?php echo $registro['data_acesso']; ?></th>
                        <th><?php echo tempo_corrido("m/d/Y H:i:s");
                    //echo $registro = @$str_ano, @$str_mes, @$str_dia,' ', @$str_hora, @$str_min, @$str_seg,  ' atrás'; ?>



                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    <?php
    }else{
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>Nenhum usuário encontrado!</div>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara você esta passando o valor errado para a função, e dentro dela esta pegando o valor de forma errada.

Troque a parte do código que chama a função

```
tempo_corrido("m/d/Y H:i:s");
```

para

```
tempo_corrido($registro['data_acesso']);
```

Ou seja, assim você esta passa para a função calcular a data **($registro['data_acesso']**), que é a que você quer calcular.

E dentro da função, retire essa linha

```
$time = $registro['data_acesso']; // <-- aqui está o registro
```

Pois o valor de **$time** já esta sendo pego como um parâmetro da função.

Assim você vai calcular o **$time** (valor do seu registro) com **$now** (a data atual)

Veja se funciona tudo ok ae.

Comment: Perfeito VALEUUU era isso mesmo :D